# Click check box with ember-cli-page-object

Tags: ember.js, pageobjects, acceptance-testing

I have a form with an input like so:

`{{input type="checkbox" class="foo"}}`

I want to click on in and then submit. My page object is like this

```
export default create({
  form: {
    selectFoo: clickable('.foo'),
    submit: clickable('#search'),
  },
});
```

However I can't select the checkbox and then submit. What am I doing wrong? I have my form stuff in `page.form` so it's easier to abstract out from all the other stuff on the page.

My test is like this:

```
page.form.selectFoo();
page.form.submit();
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after `selectFoo()`, do you see that the checkbox is checked?  And then, make sure that `$('#search')` finds the button.  Maybe you need to add a `wait`